# How Can I Find Multiple Keywords in Dictionary Keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-search

I want to search a dictionary that has a title as the key, and a http link as the value assigned to that key. I wanna function that searches through the dictionary, searching for a key that contains all the keywords that i put into the function, and if it does not find any keys with the keywords, it returns nothing. Here is the dict:

I've tried if and in statements but nothing so far.

```
dict = {
   'adidas originals yung-1 - core black / white':
        'https://kith.com/products/adidas-originals-yung-1-core-black-white',
   'adidas originals yung-1 - grey one / white': 
        'https://kith.com/products/adidas-originals-yung-1-grey-one-white',
   'hoka one tor ultra high 2 wp boot - black': 
        'https://kith.com/products/hoka-one-tor-ultra-high-2-wp-black'}
```

Let's say I wanna search for black and ultra, the function would return the third item in the dictionary cause `hoka one tor ultra high 2 wp boot - black'` contains the keywords black and ultra. If it doesn't contain all the keywords I put in, it would return nothing in the dictionary.

Comment: post what you've tried

Comment: It sounds like you want code.  Here's some psdeudocode.  Store the dictionary keys in a list.  Then for each key in the key list, use in to see if the key item contains all the required keywords.  If yes, save the key and continue.  Finally, look through your list of saved keys and get the url associated with each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a function that takes a list of keywords and checks that each keyword is represented in a value, you could do something like.

```
keywords = ['black', 'ultra'] 

def dict_search(list_of_keywords):
    for key in dict.keys():
        if all(x in key for x in list_of_keywords):
            return(key)

In [1]: dict_search(keywords)
hoka one tor ultra high 2 wp boot - black
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys of a dictionary just like this:

```
for item in dic:
    if searchterm in item:
        print('do something')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you can do something like this:

```
def getUrl(keyword):
    return [dict[key] for key in dict.keys() if keyword in key]
```

if I call this with `keyword = 'black' it returns:

```
['https://kith.com/products/hoka-one-tor-ultra-high-2-wp-black', 'https://kith.com/products/adidas-originals-yung-1-core-black-white']
```

This should return the list of urls corresponding to keys containing `keyword`.

If you have more than one `keyword` this should do the trick:

```
def getUrl(keywords):
    return [dict[key] for key in dict.keys() if len([keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword in key])>0]
```

if I call this with `keywords = ['black','ultra']` it returns this:

```
['https://kith.com/products/hoka-one-tor-ultra-high-2-wp-black', 'https://kith.com/products/adidas-originals-yung-1-core-black-white']
```

They both return `[]` in case of no keys found.